# nvd3 line with focus chart date range of the slider is mismatching with the main chart date range

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

Please see the attached Screen shot for nvd3 line with focus chart. The Date Range I have selected in the slider is not matching the date range that is appearing in the main chart. Is there any bug in nvd3 line with focus chart or am I doing any mistake?

[image: mismatch in the selected date range of slider to main chart]

The following is my service to return the data to controller :

```
angular.module('myApp').service(
        'DashboardsDataService',
        function() {


    this.getNetSpendOverTimeData = function(selectedAccount,
                        carriesList, fDate, tDate) {
                    var selectedCarriers = null;

                    if (carriesList == null) {
                        alert("Please select Carriers from the Filters.");
                        return false;
                    }

                    var selectedAccountId = selectedAccount.value;
                    var selectedAccTd = null;
                    var prefixForSelectedAccount = selectedAccountId.substr(0, 2);
                    if (prefixForSelectedAccount = "CU") {
                        selectedCustomerId = selectedAccountId.replace("CU", "");
                        selectedCustomerId = selectedCustomerId.trim();
                        selectedAccTd = selectedCustomerId;
                    } else {
                        if (prefixForSelectedAccount = "SG") {
                            selectedShipperGroup = selectedAccountId.replace("SG",
                                    "");
                            selectedShipperGroup = selectedShipperGroup.trim();
                            selectedAccTd = selectedShipperGroup;
                        }
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < carriesList.length; i++) {
                        if (selectedCarriers !== null
                                || typeof selectedCarriers !== "undefined"
                                || selectedCarriers !== '') {
                            selectedCarriers = selectedCarriers + ","
                                    + carriesList[i].catgId;
                        } else {
                            selectedCarriers = carriesList[i].catgId;
                        }
                    }

                    var formattedFromDate = this.convertDateObjToStringFormat(fDate);
                    var formattedToDate = this.convertDateObjToStringFormat(tDate);

                var originalRequest = $.ajax({
                        async : false,
                        url : "/dash/dashboard2ajax.do",
                        type : "POST",
                        data : {
                            action : 'getNetSpendOverTime',
                            customerId : selectedAccTd,
                            carriersId : selectedCarriers,
                            fromDate : formattedFromDate,
                            toDate : formattedToDate
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(originalRequest) {
                            var res = originalRequest;
                            data = res.ResultSet.Response;
                            // alert("data" + data);
                        }
                    });

                /*  data = [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1181,
                                    "x": 1391299200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1183,
                                    "x": 1391385600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 977,
                                    "x": 1391472000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1136,
                                    "x": 1391558400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 994,
                                    "x": 1391644800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 944,
                                    "x": 1391731200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 568,
                                    "x": 1391817600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1025,
                                    "x": 1391904000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1314,
                                    "x": 1391990400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 882,
                                    "x": 1392076800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1160,
                                    "x": 1392163200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1143,
                                    "x": 1392249600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1048,
                                    "x": 1392336000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 752,
                                    "x": 1392422400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 753,
                                    "x": 1392508800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 972,
                                    "x": 1392595200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1027,
                                    "x": 1392681600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1176,
                                    "x": 1392768000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1689,
                                    "x": 1392854400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1188,
                                    "x": 1392940800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 897,
                                    "x": 1393027200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 2579,
                                    "x": 1393200000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1212,
                                    "x": 1393286400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1324,
                                    "x": 1393372800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1476,
                                    "x": 1393459200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1036,
                                    "x": 1393545600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 923,
                                    "x": 1393632000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1587,
                                    "x": 1393718400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 285,
                                    "x": 1393804800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1809,
                                    "x": 1393891200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1742,
                                    "x": 1393977600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 2233,
                                    "x": 1394064000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 761,
                                    "x": 1394150400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 2727,
                                    "x": 1394323200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1214,
                                    "x": 1394409600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1664,
                                    "x": 1394496000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1790,
                                    "x": 1394582400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1496,
                                    "x": 1394668800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1291,
                                    "x": 1394755200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1428,
                                    "x": 1394841600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 744,
                                    "x": 1394928000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1391,
                                    "x": 1395014400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1438,
                                    "x": 1395100800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1801,
                                    "x": 1395187200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1840,
                                    "x": 1395273600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 931,
                                    "x": 1395360000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 987,
                                    "x": 1395446400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1012,
                                    "x": 1395532800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1404,
                                    "x": 1395619200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1776,
                                    "x": 1395705600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1593,
                                    "x": 1395792000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1746,
                                    "x": 1395878400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1377,
                                    "x": 1395964800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 991,
                                    "x": 1396051200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1036,
                                    "x": 1396137600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1239,
                                    "x": 1396220400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1482,
                                    "x": 1396306800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1533,
                                    "x": 1396393200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1558,
                                    "x": 1396479600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1267,
                                    "x": 1396566000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1463,
                                    "x": 1396652400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1339,
                                    "x": 1396738800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1482,
                                    "x": 1396825200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 2011,
                                    "x": 1396911600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1836,
                                    "x": 1396998000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 2090,
                                    "x": 1397084400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1531,
                                    "x": 1397170800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 906,
                                    "x": 1397257200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1207,
                                    "x": 1397343600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1860,
                                    "x": 1397430000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1276,
                                    "x": 1397516400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1802,
                                    "x": 1397602800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1808,
                                    "x": 1397689200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1647,
                                    "x": 1397775600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 609,
                                    "x": 1397862000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1820,
                                    "x": 1397948400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1379,
                                    "x": 1398034800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1801,
                                    "x": 1398121200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1894,
                                    "x": 1398207600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1533,
                                    "x": 1398294000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 925,
                                    "x": 1398380400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 860,
                                    "x": 1398466800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 977,
                                    "x": 1398553200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1373,
                                    "x": 1398639600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1557,
                                    "x": 1398726000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1245,
                                    "x": 1398812400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1538,
                                    "x": 1398898800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1321,
                                    "x": 1398985200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 698,
                                    "x": 1399071600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1035,
                                    "x": 1399158000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1542,
                                    "x": 1399244400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1613,
                                    "x": 1399330800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1695,
                                    "x": 1399417200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1742,
                                    "x": 1399503600000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1336,
                                    "x": 1399590000000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 617,
                                    "x": 1399676400000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 790,
                                    "x": 1399762800000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1589,
                                    "x": 1399849200000
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "series": 0,
                                    "y": 1236,
                                    "x": 1399935600000
                                  }
                                ],
                                "key": "USPS"
                              }
                            ];
               */




                    return data;

                }
        });
```

The following is the code in my controller :

```
$scope.netspendovertime_data = DashboardsDataService.getNetSpendOverTimeData(selectedAccount, selectedCarrierList, fromDate, toDate);
```

In my jsp page, full json data is being displayed even with Ajax request, when I have displayed using :

```
 <div>
    <pre class="code">{{ netspendovertime_data | json }}</pre>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you put your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so someone can have a look.

Comment: Please find my plinker at http://plnkr.co/edit/No1VCuUHf2XjiLiHAWU2?p=preview. I could not able to replicate the issue and every thing works fine in plnkr. However in my application the problem still persist. So, I replaced my Ajax request and hardcoded the data. Then every thing works fine as expected. May be some Angularjs expert can address my problem why the issue is occurring with Ajax request but not with hard coded data? As I have used chart with Angular snap, I thought may be drag behavior of snap is conflicting with the chart drag. But from my plunker I realized it is not the case.

Comment: I have edited my question with the service and the controller code I have used to get the data using Ajax call.